# Do mosfets only output a portion of their drain voltage when measured at their source? Why?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, low-power

I built a BMS battery cutoff detection circuit for an RV using a mosfet inverter and a second mosfet to deliver a low impedance path to the vehicle's starter battery.

Am I underpowering the gate of FET1, or is 10.4V at Vout normal behavior? I tried changing R3 to 5K and it made no difference.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've built a [common drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain) buffer using FET2 - the characteristic behavior of such buffers is that the source voltage will follow the gate voltage minus a Vgs drop needed to turn on the MOSFET.

The simplest option might be to use a single relay that's rated for enough power - if you want the battery to be disconnected when V_house is present, you can wire V_house to the relay coil and use normally-closed logic for the current path. Make sure the relay can handle the necessary current, especially if there's a chance you might be opening/closing it when operating the starter and/or other loads.

There's also a MOSFET solution that can be used if you absolutely want to avoid relays for some reason:

Assuming that your battery load *must* be switched at the high-side, if you want fully on-off switching and want to still use MOSFETs, you can use a high-current PMOS instead (note different relative position of source/drain terminals):

[image]

(note that I used an extra nMOS inverter rather than simply putting the PMOS directly to V_house, to avoid any potential issues with mismatches between V_house and V_s). I'm also assuming that you're just sensing for V_house being present or not; if you need more precise sensing, you're going to want a comparator and precision reference instead (plus one discrete pFET and some passives).

Some additional schematic notes: Your voltage sources are not drawn as I would expect -- the positive terminal floating is unexpected. You'll want to either draw the supply voltage as a rail (as I drew), or use a source correctly connected to the ground that it's referenced to.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my incorrectly drawn sources. This circuit is actually just to drive an alternator regulator's Feature-In port which disables charging if it receives a low impedance path to >4V, so my circuit works but I want to understand the 10.4V output. I have a 48V 400AH battery bank and a 48V 100A alternator, so if one pack in the bank cuts off I must stop charging to avoid a possible load dump. Why is the voltage drop to turn the mosfet on 1.6? How do I calculate that and get ~10.4V from a 12V source? The common drain buffer answer is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: @BeachInMexico  I think you are misunderstanding this answer.  You accidentally built a common drain buffer, which is not what you intended to do.  Your circuit works but it's a bad circuit (for this application).  The suggestion is to either use a PMOS switch (i.e. "high-side switch") or a relay.  You cannot do what you want using an NMOS switch which is "low-side".  If you hook it up the way you initially did, it's connected as an amplifier (buffer) which exhibits the voltage drop equal to the threshold voltage [see VGS(th) in the IRF530N datasheet].  It will burn unnecessary power.

Comment: Thank you @SteKulov! I don't know why I didn't just think of a PMOS instead. It's so much simpler. Thank you @nanofarad as well! Relays are out because the input signal is continuous and may stay high for months at a time. I need a positive output from the second source (Vstarter) when the first source (Vhouse) is open circuited, so generating a pulse from that open circuit condition to trigger a latching relay, and another pulse to reset it all requires more complexity than just using one PMOS.

Comment: One final question for @nanofarad (or anyone else): What is meant "(note that I used an extra nMOS inverter rather than simply putting the PMOS directly to V_house, to avoid any potential issues with mismatches between V_house and V_s). I have a 48V house battery bank, and a 12V starter battery (for the signal)." I plan to divide Vhouse voltage down to a suitable level for the FET. But assuming I was trying to do what you originally wrote, why would I need another FET "to avoid any potential issues with mismatches"? Both sources will vary in normal conditions: Vhouse 40-60V, Vstarter 11-15V.

Comment: @BeachInMexico there's enough variation in the vhouse and vstarter voltages that a PMOS might be wrongly on or off when not desired, because a PMOS gate is referenced to its source which will vary from 11 to 15 V. Meanwhile, a divided Vhouse will itself vary from 10-15V depending on the divider, and this will make the transistor potentially turn on prematurely when vstarter is on the high end of the range and vhouse is at the lower end (or worse, oscillate as it turns on, vstarter gets loaded and drops, gets unloaded and rises)

Comment: @nanofarad Thank you! You've been a great help. So if the source swings from 11-15V, would there be a 4V swing of the gate threshold? If so, can I just ensure that when dividing Vhouse 48V nominal, there's still plenty of headroom above the gate threshold? For instance, 100K/47K resistors, leaving 12.8V-18V (Vhouse 40V - 58V). That way even if Vsource swings 11-15, the lowest the gate would see is 12.8 - 4 = 8.8V, which is still well above threshold. Or am I misunderstanding exactly how a PMOS gate is referenced to its source?

Comment: @BeachInMexico With that specific division, vhouse's divider output (i.e. the PMOS gate) could be at 12.8 while Vstarter is at 15 V (the source of the FET is attached to Vstarter). This makes the gate-source voltage 2.2 V, which is large enough that it could make the PMOS leak and overheat under some conditions. One option is to make the divider output a somewhat higher voltage -- as long as you don't exceed the maximum Vgs rating of the MOSFET, having the divided-down Vhouse be greater than Vstarter shouldn't pose an issue

Comment: @nanofarad Thank you again. Could I just use a ZVP4424A with a 40V Vgs max, and then divide 48V Vhouse down with 75K/75K Ohm, yielding 20-30V, which would always be well above Vstarter? You are a truly kind and helpful person. You may have saved me a great deal of stress. Thank you!!

Comment: @BeachInMexico This should work, as long as the 'feature-in" port of the alternator doesn't draw too much current. The FET you showed is pretty small and will just barely survive 200 mA according to a skim of the datasheet.

Comment: @nanofarad Thank you! I just finished comparing 30V and 40V options and was liking FQP12P10 with 30Vgs and 11.5A Id. I'd divide at 75K/50K yielding 16-24V, which still keeps me above 15V. Any issues you see with that? I'm also thinking of using a basic diode AND circuit to let all 4 Vhouse batteries drive one p-FET instead of using four. Again, thank you!! Can I repay the kindness with a donation or pay it forward to the next person?